# Xcode crashes when debugging in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, xcode7

Anytime I try to PO values from the debugger while at a breakpoint Xcode crashes. This happens with Swift, but not Objective-C.

I'm running Xcode 7.2

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: @RashwanL Yes, I'm using AlamoFire, SwiftyJSON, and Eureka (installed via Carthage). And also Parse and Bolts (imported manually). No CocoPods.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known bug, check out [this](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/832) and [this](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/727) threads to read more. They seem to be using similar frameworks as you use.

I can recommend you to send a bug to Apple, you can do that [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).